# Web Inspector In XCode IOS Simulator Not Showing

Tags: xcode, ios9, simulator

I am trying to fix an issue in the iPad version of a site and can't seem to get the web inspector to show up in the XCode IOS simulator for an iPad2.

I have gone into the settings for Safari and there should be an "Advanced", which is where the web inspector setting is, but it isn't there.

My settings: http://concrete.metooplace.com/application/themes/dcc_theme/img/SimulatorScreenShot.png

What do I need to do to enable this?